# select Variable products with image marker

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

hello everyone sorry for bad grammar. my English is bad. 
i am making a site for renting exhibition stand and I'm using image marker to user click on stands in image to select stand number.
i use this code to change selected variable product

```
var element = document.getElementById('pa_%d8%ba%d8%b1%d9%81%d9%87');
        element.value = $marker["context"]["innerText"];
```

but it only change it in the select form and it won't trigger JavaScript that listen to form change. how can i change it?
thank for helping

Answer (score 0):

it's been a long time.i did have find the answer my self for a while but i forget to post it. 
i change the code to this code to change and refresh variable product.

```
jQuery('select').val($marker.text().toLowerCase());
jQuery('.variations_form.cart').trigger( 'reload_product_variations' );
```